# Call onResume() method from Asynctask's onPostExecute() Method

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onresume

I am calling Asynctask and after complition of doInBackground(String... arg0) i want to call onResume() in onPostExecute() Method.

Comment: Dont call Activity life cycle methods on your own..make the code in onResume to separate method and call it..

Comment: call method as `ActivityName.this.onResume();`

Comment: Its not a good idea to call Activity life cycle method your own

Comment: The latter is not intended to be called by you, it's a convenience method that tidies up or readies the activity when its state changes to resume..Implement another procedure that's called in your override of onResume().

Comment: a BIG RED warning message :) don't do it this way , PLEASE.

Comment: You may end up with `onResume()` to be called more than once. One by the Android system as Activity life cycle callback and one by your AsyncTask. However, if you are going to hold your UI thread to wait for AsyncTask to finish, then what you used it in the first place?

Comment: also why do you specifically want to call `onResume()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afte AsyncTask Complete 
put this line in onPostExecute()

```
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This Will call onResume() Automaticly

or if this is not Work then call Dialog box.
when Dialog box open Activity gosein onPause()
and when DialogBox is close it will call onResume()
this will work

Answer (score 3):

You should not call explicitly activity lifecycle methods, they usually call base class versions - ie. super.onResume(), so you might mess with activity state. Instead move related code from onResume to some outer function, and call this function instead in your onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call Activity.this.onResume(); on your postexecution method

Answer (score 0):

1.First of you need to take reference of your Activity say MainActivity in your asynkTask class by doing this.
     MainActivity activity=(MainActivity)context.
                  context is the variable that you pass during calling the asynktask class from your activity.
2.now you can call easily by doing this.
       activity.onResume().

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do that?

if your async task is a nested class just call a method directly.

```
public MainActivity extends Activity{
    //all the usual functionalities

    public void methodAfterAsyncTask(){
        //do stuff here
    }

    private CustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        public onPostExecute(){
            super.onPostExecute();
            methodAfterAsyncTask();
        }
    }

}
```

If you are a strong believer of OOP and like clean code :)..I use this method

MainActivity .java

```
public MainActivity extends Activity{
    //all the usual functionalities

   public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        new CustomAsyncTask(new AsyncListener(){
               public void postTaskMethod(){
               //do stuff here
               }

        }).execute();
   }



}
```

AsyncListener.java

```
public interface AsyncListener{
    void postTaskMethod();
}
```

CustomAsyncTask.java

```
 publicCustomAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        private AsyncListener listener;

        public CustomAsyncTask(AsyncListener listener){
                    this.listener=listener;
        }

        @Override
        public onPostExecute(){
            super.onPostExecute();
            if(null!=listener)
            listener.postTaskMethod();
        }
    }
```